# Exported mesh in Gmsh V2 Ascii Format is empty

Tags: mesh

I made a trinagle in Gmsh. The .geo file looks like this:

```
// Gmsh project created on Tue Jun 30 13:15:37 2020
SetFactory("OpenCASCADE");
//+
Point(1) = {0, 0, 0, 1.0};
//+
Point(2) = {1, 0, 0, 1.0};
//+
Point(3) = {0, 1, 0, 1.0};
//+
Line(1) = {1, 2};
//+
Line(2) = {2, 3};
//+
Line(3) = {3, 1};
//+
Curve Loop(1) = {1, 2, 3};
//+
Plane Surface(1) = {1};
```

Now I need a .msh V2 Ascii file. I export it (I tried checking the options "Save all elements" and "Save parametric coordinates" and I always get the following:

```
$MeshFormat
2.2 0 8
$EndMeshFormat
$Nodes
0
$EndNodes
$Elements
0
$EndElements
```

So it's basically empty and I just can't figure out whats wrong.

Answer (score 0):

It is highly likely, that you have not generated the mesh yet. Thus, there are no elements to be exported.

Since you have a surface model, you are probably up for a 2-D mesh:

```
Mesh->2D
```

After that, you can proceed with exporting it in a .msh V2 format as you identified in your question.

The same can be achieved by pressing <kbd>m</kbd>-><kbd>2</kbd> on the keyboard.

---

While this will work, the model you currently have is missing  [`Physical Surface`](https://gmsh.info/doc/texinfo/gmsh.html#Surfaces)s. And, potentially, [`Physical Lines`](https://gmsh.info/doc/texinfo/gmsh.html#Curves) if you are interested in 1-D meshes as well. By default, GMSH outputs all elements; however, very often one needs finer control over what mesh elements are exported and with which tags.

Answer (score 0):

Your mesh is a 2D problem. You can generate the msh file in ascii v2 by exectuing in the terminal:

```
gmsh -2 <input_name>.geo -o <output_name>.msh -format msh2
```

The `-2` indicates the dimension (for a 3D problem, it would be `-3`) and `msh2` will save the file in ascii v2.